# Pass elements of global variable array from keypad in Arduino

Tags: arrays, arduino, keypad

Currently elements of array `a1[2]` are initialised in code but I want to pass this element of global variable array `a1[2]` from keypad as v1.

Here is my code:

```
#include "Keypad.h"
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

unsigned int a1[2]={1,10}; //global variable
//unsigned int a1[2] = {1,v1} //not working
/.. 
keypad initialization
.../

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(1,1);
  lcd.print("Press # to GO");
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Enter v1: ");
  v1 = GetNumber();
}

void loop() {
  ...
}

int GetNumber() {
   ...
   ....
  return num;
}
```

Comment: **Arduino is not C**

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int a1[2] = {1,v1} //not working
```

Of course, v1 not yet defined. I think you want:

```
unsigned int a1[2] = {1,0}; 
unsigned int v1;
```

Then, below `v1 = GetNumber();` add `a1[2] = v1;`.

I don't understand why `a1` is an array, but then I don't understand your objective.

The block below doesn't seem to be part of anything.

```
return num;
}
```